# Actualizar registros con php

Tags: php, html

```html
<?php
  
    session_start();

    if (empty($_SESSION['email'])) {

  ?>
            <script language='JavaScript'>
              location.href = "index.php";
            </script>
  <?php
    }

    include "conexion.php";

    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from usuarioss where correo = '$email'");
    $arr=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
    ?>
<div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Correo electronico<span class="kv-reqd">*</span></label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required value="<?php echo $arr['3']?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pwd">Contraseña<span class="kv-reqd">*</span></label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" required value="<?php echo $arr['5']?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fname">Nombre(s)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" required value="<?php echo $arr['1']?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lname">Apellido(s)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" required value="<?php echo $arr['2']?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <hr>
                <div class="text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
```

Tengo ese formulario donde ya mando a llamar unos datos de la base de datos, el problema que tengo es al momento de actualizar, me sale un error, les anexo mi codigo para la actualizacion:

```
  <?php 
    session_start();
    include 'conexion.php';
    //llega los campos de la tabla mediante la metodo post
    $email=$_POST['nombre'];
    $nom=$_POST['fname'];
    $ap=$_POST['lname'];
    $correo=$_POST['email'];
    $clave = $_POST['pwd'];

    //elaborar la consulta
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuarioss SET nombre='$nom', apellido='$ap', correo='$correo', clave='$clave' where correo='$email'");

    if ($consulta){
    //prepare la consult
    //redireccionamos a la siguiente pagina
        header("refresh:2; conf.php");
    }else
    {
        echo "No actualiza...<br>";
    }
```

Si quito la condicion where si actualiza pero todos los registros y en este caso solo debe de ser actualizar los datos de la persona logueada, me podrian ayudar haciendome ver mi error, por favor.......................................................................................

Comment: Tienes esto `$email=$_POST['nombre']; $correo=$_POST['email'];` deberías cambiarle los nombres a la variable $email porque no concuerda con lo que obtiene de $_POS[], si no te vas a confundir, además de que el campo correo debería de ser único, para que solo puedas editar los campos de la persona que ha iniciado sesión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que el error está en que en el WHERE la variable que le pasas es incorrecta, en su caso debería ser:

```
   $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuarioss SET nombre='$nom', apellido='$ap', correo='$correo', clave='$clave' where correo='$correo'")
```

Comment: Si era eso amigo, gracias.